# Phonegap orientation lock does is not working

Tags: cordova, locking, screen, phonegap

I have a problem with PhoneGap and screen orientation locking. I use this in my config.xml file:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

The problem is that the screen on the android device is not locked as portrait and my Android phone is still able to rotate the screen if the sensor is activated. I have tested this only on Android (I don't know if on iOS is the same problem).

I also tried to add this in my onDeviceReady function:

```
screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
```

also tried this:

```
window.screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
```

Nothing worked to lock the screen rotation. To build the apk file I use this builder: https://build.phonegap.com

Answer (score 1):

I observed the same thing, when using the combination of "Desktop App" and "Developer Mobile App"

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```

do not work. I believe this is because the "Developer Mobile App" is like a pre-built container.

When I actually used the service to build then downloaded and installed the .apk on my phone the screen rotation lock worked.

Comment: I assure you that I have those 2 lines in my config.xml file and nothing works, the screen remains unlocked. I don't use the Developer Mobile App, I use the real app, build from build.phonegap.com (apk file)

Comment: Update: Ok, it seems like it worked after I deacrivated the "Hydration" option from build.phonegap.com, thanks!